# Running integration test inside google cloud

Tags: cloud, integration-testing, postman, access-token

We are trying to do integration testing for an **Api**. The endpoints use access-token for authentication, It is possible to add token in **postman collection** files and run the tests but this is not ideal as nobody wants to keep access token inside code and it has limited life or expiry. So the question, is it possible to create an **environment** for testing inside **google project** where the api is located, kind of using **Google cloud secrets** to be used as **environment variable** in **postman/newman**.

Comment: Seems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You may use postman environment variables or global postman variables for start call and receive new token, than save it to variable and than use in another calls. 
Detailed about this variables and examples how save available in my presentation - https://github.com/AndriiStepura/letslearnapitesting/blob/master/StartTestingApiWithPostman.pdf
At last page also examples how to run Newman with environment JSON